# Trying to program for y in y=mx+b, but not working?

Tags: c++

I wanted to start learning how to program, so I asked my math professor if he had a book that I could borrow. He did and so I have been reading a C++ book from ~1994 (it still has a floppy disk :P). Anyway, I made it to a point in it and it sets up a program that calculates y in y=mx+b. Pretty simple, but I decided to try it out and it is not working. I would really like to figure out why it is not working and fix it.

Here is the code for it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; //not in the book: added by me after some Googling
int main() {
    cout << "Input m: " << flush;
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Y-intercept: " << flush;
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "X coordinate of interest: " << flush;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    int y;
    y = m * x + b;
    cout << "y = " << y << "when m = " << m << "; " << "b = " << b << "; x = " << x << endl;
}
```

edit: Sorry. Forgot to describe what was going on. lol. The program executes properly until it it comes to displaying the final line. After submitting "X coordinate of interest: " the program simply exits. I mean I am no expert in C++, but should the final `cout` write to the console?

And I know it is really outdated, but I really just want a platform to stand on when I begin to look at the newage languages. The book itself is only about 700 pages, and there is a LOT of explaining in it, so it is not very much code wise. I have probably 10 to 20 700 page pdfs on Java and C#/C++/C all written within the past six years. So I'll be good. Just want a starting point. :) Plus this book explains a lot about how a computer works and certain jargon that some of the newer books just don't.

Comment: what is the error message you receive when compiling? Or what is the output and what are you expecting? I currently don't know what the exact problem is.

Comment: What's not working? One specific input? Every input? Compilation?

Comment: Just closes when you type the x variable? `getchar()` or `cin >> variable` should do the trick

Comment: Note that this program accepts integers (in a limited range) only. Attempting to type in numbers with decimals, like English `3.14` or mainland European `3,14`, will cause internal failure to interpret the input. In order to support numbers with decimals and the English notation, just change the type `int` to `double`.

Comment: If your book tries to make you use `cout` and `cin` without the line `using namespace std;` I recommend you get another book.

Comment: C++ was first standardized in 1998, and the standard has some differences from the non-standard implementations that came before (such as the `std` namespace), so be aware that your 1994 book is teaching you outdated material that differs from modern best practice.  You'd be better off finding an up-to-date C++ tutorial on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common windows cmd problem. Either run the program through cmd, type in the executable name, or add `getchar` or `cin >> variable` to the end of the program.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I added `cin >> y` to the end to conform to what was already typed and it worked. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in Visual Studio when you run a program with debugging (F5) the console instance is closed automatically. You can either add a input line to the end of the program as others have mentioned or run the program without debugging (Ctrl+F5) and the console window will pause and let you see the output at the end of the programs execution.